# Database query output to CSV

Tags: oracle, powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

Below is my PowerShell code and it is working fine.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")

$constr = "User Id=system;Password=pass;Data Source=API"
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
$conn.Open()
$sql="select * from dba_users"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

while($reader.Read()){
  $reader.GetString(0)
}

$conn.Close()
```

The problem is I want to export result to CSV. How to do this in PowerShell? Also, how can I show it in tabular format in PowerShell screen or output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something like this in the past I havent exported it as a csv but it should work.

```
$someArray = @()
    #read all rows into a hash table
    while ($reader.Read())
    {
        $row = @{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
        {
            $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
        }
        #convert hashtable into an array of PSObjects
        $someArray += new-object psobject -property $row            
    }
$conn.Close()
$someArray | export-csv C:\temp\someFile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try tomorrow and let you know. Voted Up

Answer (score 1):

Build custom objects from the fields of each record, then export the list of objects to a CSV:

```
$colNames = $reader.GetSchemaTable() | select -Expand ColumnName

$data = while ($reader.Read()) {
  $obj = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject

  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $colNames.Count; $i++) {
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $colNames[$i] -Value $reader.GetString($i)
  }

  $obj
}

$data | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Code adopted from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx) (about halfway down the page, but you may want to read the article in its entirety).

Pipe the data into `Format-Table` to get tabular output in the PowerShell console:

```
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Are you sure about that because most of things are out of my head.

Comment: @404 I can't test this since I don't have access to an Oracle database, but I'd expect it to work. The approach is pretty much the same as the one suggested by Dane Boulton, except that it avoids appending to an array in a loop.